# How to delete a shipping address in Google Photos (photo book)?

Tags: google-photos

When ordering a photo book within Google Photos, the address is obviously stored in their website.

However, as it seems there is no option to delete an incorrect address. Or not even to edit an existing address.

In the **order status** it is stated directly below the address given:

> To change shipping address follow instructions here.

which links to https://support.google.com/photos/answer/7378942?p=change_address#changeshipping

However, it says nothing about deleting an address, instead:

> To change shipping address after buying, cancel your order and buy the book again.

But no way to delete former addresses.

How to delete existing addresses then?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

Go to your Google.
Click your account icon on the top-right.
Click "Manage Your Google Account."
On the left, click "Payments and Subscriptions."
Click "Change Payment Methods."
Click the tab "Addresses."

Now you can remove any unwanted shipping addresses.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out there is "*no way to delete former addresses.*"

**Google need to have some address for any buys to go through**.
Google keep former addresses -I guess- as a proof just in case there are [future issues with your past orders](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/6962128?hl=en).

As an alternative you could [Change or delete a payments profile](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7644075) by going to [Permanently end your Google Pay service](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7643930)

> ***TIP***

***Before taking any steps I think you should:***

1. On your computer, open [photos.google.com](https://photos.google.com/).
2. Sign in to your Google Account.
3. On the left, click `Print store`.
4. Under `Past orders` select a photo book.
5. To **save a PDF copy**, click `More` and then Download PDF of book.
6. Repeat as many times as needed.

Also read:

- [Change your home or billing address](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7644076)
  *(You can update your home address in Google Pay or change an address associated with a specific payment method.)*
  *(You can only create one profile per country.)*
- [Change or delete a payments profile](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7644075)
  *(Once you’ve created a payments profile in Google Pay, you can make changes to it or close it.)*